# Is there an AWS-native mysql client library for nodejs?

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

When creating a NodeJS API that accesses my serverless mysql cluster, the notes out there all point to NPM-loading the mysql package. I really try to avoid contaminating my lambdas with NPM and all the other dependencies that are going to spawn.
Is there no AWS native mysql client like the one for dynamoDb?

To clarify further, I'm looking for the mysql equivalent to this:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.html

The advantage here is no package installation required and still being able to write classes without all the overhead code for managing types etc etc.

This project seems to acknowledge some work is needed in this regard:
https://github.com/jeremydaly/data-api-client

---

**Update**: So I bit the bullet and npm-installed a mysql package.Total cost is 11 modules and just 1.42Mb (below the 3Mb limit I like to set). I'm able to run all my CRUD ops as well as db and table management on Aurora.

If you're not doing sophisticated cluster management and are happy to leave that to Aurora, I think this is good enough.

I see a lot of code out there for lambdas crowded with AWS libraries, data-clients; this pushes the lambda to more than 20Mb. Totally not needed; for the rare case of cluster management involvement, you could just use a different lambda with those packages.

Answer (score 1):

So to my knowledge there's isn't an out of the box query interface for anything other than Aurora Serverless - so you'd need nodes MySQL library or something.

Aurora docs are here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/RDSDataService.html#executeSql-property

Comment: They do appear to be using Aurora Serverless MySQL

Comment: Yeah although sometimes people say serverless because it's RDS and they don't have to manage it.

Comment: Thanks for the link. What I had in mind was a something similar to the DocumentClient like you have for DynamoDb here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.html
I did find this project which seems to acknowledge some work's needed:
https://github.com/jeremydaly/data-api-client

Comment: Are you using aurora serverless?

Comment: Yeah so that's your option really either include the NodeJS MySQL npm module and query that way or if you don't want the extra weight you can just use the RDSDataService to execute queries.

Answer (score 1):

Since you state you are using "serverless MySQL" I assume you are actually using MySQL compatible Aurora Serverless.

There is not a "native MySQL client" built into AWS Lambda, but that isn't really what you are looking for anyway. What you are looking for is the [Aurora Serverless Data API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/data-api.html), which is part of the AWS SDK that is "built into" the AWS Lambda environment.

Comment: Thanks for the link. What I had in mind was a something similar to the DocumentClient like you have for DynamoDb here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.html
I did find this project which seems to acknowledge some work's needed:
https://github.com/jeremydaly/data-api-client